# Convert Object to Array Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, google-visualization

I'm working with google charts using angularJs. The problem am facing is that the data used in the chart must be an array but the type of data I have is an object. So how can I convert it to an array.
The data I have :

```
Object {Normale: 1129, urgente: 153}
```

The array am trying to have would be something like this:

```
[['priorite', 'nb'], ['urgente', 1129],['normale', 153]]
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com) is perfect to do this easily.

1. Use [toPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs) method to convert your object to pairs
2. Use Array.unshift method to insert`['priorite', 'nb']` at first position
3. That's all ! ;)

```js
var obj = {Normale: 1129, urgente: 153};
var arr = _.toPairs(obj);
arr.unshift(['priorite', 'nb']);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

You can also order priorities by their value (first is Urgent, last is VeryLow) this way  :

```js
var obj = {VeryLow: 100, Normal: 500, Urgent: 1000, Low: 250};
var arr = _.toPairs(obj);
arr = arr.sort(function compare(a, b) {
  if (a[1] > b[1])
     return -1;
  if (a[1] < b[1])
     return 1;
  return 0;
});
arr.unshift(['priorite', 'nb']);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [];
angular.forEach(function(obj) {
    myArray.push({"priorite": obj.Normale, "nb": obj.urgente});
});
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` on the `Object.keys`:

```js
var o = {
  Normale: 1129,
  urgente: 153
};

var a = Object.keys(o).reduce((a, b) => a.concat({
  priorite: b,
  nb: o[b]
}), []);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but can I also have the objet converted this way :[['priorite', 'nb'], ['urgente', 1129],['normale', 153]]?